# Not Work \pause in beamer

Tags: beamer, pause

The pause does not work properly!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
%Assuming  problem is related  with xepersian
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{FreeFarsi}
\raggedleft

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
این اولین متن،
\pause
این دومین متن
\pause
و این سومین متن هست.
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item
آیتم اول
\pause
\item
آیتم دوم
\pause
\item
آیتم سوم
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

upload
[Output](http://s8.picofile.com/d/8341166884/c5c7de8f-d5dd-448c-bc4c-b56a7ccd235d/exam_pause_beamer.pdf)

Comment: Welcome. Does it work if you use latin alphabet?

Comment: In Not work Persian alphabet!

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that does not rely on special fonts and letters? More people would be able to try to help you. Can you also describe what is not working properly?

Comment: It does not work properly, that is, it shows up in the second and third items

Answer (score 1):

You should use `blank line`, `before` and `after` each `\pause` in `text` as the same as below:

```
این اولین متن،

\pause

این دومین متن

\pause

و این سومین متن هست.

\pause
```

Also for `itemize` (and  `enumerate` too) you can use this structure:

---

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item
آیتم اول

\item

آیتم دوم

\item

آیتم سوم        

\end{itemize}
```

---

(or use `\pause`)

This is your codes:

---

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagemode=FullScreen,hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usepackage[%
inlinemathdigits=persian,%
displaymathdigits=persian%
]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{IRZar}
\title{توقف در محیط آیتمایز در محیط فارسی}
\author{\lr{PERSIAN ITEMIZE}}
\date{\today}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\raggedleft
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
این اولین متن،

\pause

این دومین متن

\pause

و این سومین متن هست.

\pause

\begin{itemize}[<+->]\raggedleft
\item
آیتم اول

\item

آیتم دوم

\item

آیتم سوم        

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

And this is your output:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

please look at them in `fullscreen` with the new version of adobe reader(use `Pg Up` and `Pg Dn`).

---

**Second edit:**
You should use the below `package`:

```
\usepackage[accumulated]{beamerseminar}
```

So this your codes:

---

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagemode=FullScreen,hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer}
\usepackage[accumulated]{beamerseminar}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\usepackage[%
inlinemathdigits=persian,%
displaymathdigits=persian%
]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.2]{IRZar}
\title{توقف در محیط آیتمایز در محیط فارسی}
\author{\lr{PERSIAN ITEMIZE}}
\date{\today}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\raggedleft
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}

این اولین متن،
{\overlay1\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{2}
این دومین متن}
{\overlay2
و این سومین متن هست.}

\pause

\begin{itemize}[<+->]\raggedleft
\item
آیتم اول

\item

آیتم دوم

\item

آیتم سوم        

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, The text does not appear on the same line.
این اولین متن، «مکث» این دومین متن «مکث» و این سومین متن هست.

Comment: Unfortunately in persian beamer the pause command does not work correctly to this situation. Please see the second edit.